# Pertubation of a commuting d-tuple of $2 \times 2$ matrices to a commuting *diagonalizable* d-tuple of matrices

Tags: matrices, functional-analysis, diagonalization

Does anybody know a simple proof of the following fact :

*Any $d$-tuple of commuting $2 \times 2$ matrices can be perturbed to a $d$-tuple of commuting diagonalizable $2 \times 2$ matrices*

It seems to be a very well-known fact in functional analysis, but I cannot find a simple proof of this...

Comment: If all the matrices of the $d$-tuple are the same, that's easy, as we know that the result is true for one matrix (in that example, we can juste take $B_n = \begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{n} & 1 \\ 0 & \frac{2}{n} \end{pmatrix}$ for $n$ large enough, and then take the $d$-tuple with $d$ copies of $B_n$. As those $d$ matrices are the same, they commute). The problem is when the matrices of the $d$-tuple are not all the same : how can we guarantee that the respective perturbations of each matrix will commute ?